# grep all .js urls from text file

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, grep, command

There is a File `a.txt`

```
https://site.tld/anythingjs.html
https://site.tld/b.txt
https://site.tld/a.js
https://site.tld/b.js?query=1
http://site.tld/c.js
http://site.tld/d.js
```

I want to grep all `.js` extension URLs so I tried this but it not showing `https://site.tld/b.js?query=1`

```
$ cat a.txt | grep '.js$'

https://site.tld/a.js
http://site.tld/c.js
http://site.tld/d.js
```

And when I tried this, It also select `js` name from anywhere

```
$ cat a.txt | grep '.js$*'

https://site.tld/anythingjs.html
https://site.tld/a.js
https://site.tld/b.js?query=1
http://site.tld/c.js
http://site.tld/d.js
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just escape the . with a \

```
$ cat a.txt
https://site.tld/anythingjs.html
https://site.tld/b.txt
https://site.tld/a.js
https://site.tld/b.js?query=1
http://site.tld/c.js
http://site.tld/d.js

$ grep '\.js' a.txt
https://site.tld/a.js
https://site.tld/b.js?query=1
http://site.tld/c.js
http://site.tld/d.js
```

Comment: Thank you sir,
Sir this include also .json extensions, but I need the, also so I don't have problem but if someone needed only .js then what command?

Comment: You can try this.

`grep '\.js$\|\.js?' a.txt`

Essentially `.` matches any single character. `\|` allows for matching one out of many patterns. So it matches `.js` at the end of the line or a `.js?` where `?` is the actual question mark character.